# How to configure solr 4.1 for Sitecore 8.0

Tags: solr

We need to configure Solr 4.1 for our sc8.0 u5 instance. This will be used as a platform for the website search (not the internal search).

The official doc I feel is not really helpful or incomplete.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr

To start with, it asks to place the schema in a relevant core. But which one is it.

I have installed Solr 4.1, but when adding a new core, it gives an error saying - *Could not load config for solrconfig.xml*

Could someone please help me with the right steps to setup & configure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have Solr Running Properly.
2. Copy the Solr Support Package components to bin folder.
3. Enable the solr config files and disable the Lucene configuration.
4. Configure Indexes.

You can look at this be link url for Solr Support Package details, also you can look the reference link provided in the blog post.

[Solr Support Package](https://sivalingaamorthy.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/sitecore-solr-support-package-open-source/?iframe=true&theme_preview=true)

For detailed Step by step Solr & Sitecore configuration, you can refer below links,

[Part1](http://thinking.edynamic.net/making-solr-search-work-with-sitecore-8-part-1), [Part2](http://thinking.edynamic.net/making-solr-search-work-with-sitecore-8-part-2), [Part3](http://thinking.edynamic.net/making-solr-search-work-with-sitecore-8-part-3)

Hope you will find useful.

Comment: Do I need to download the solution and compile to just get the DLLs? And also, for which version of sc/solr are they. I did read the other referenced blogs, but they are not for 4.1. Thanks for helping though

Comment: Please add detail to this answer or it becomes a link only answer please check the guidelines on [how to write a good answer](http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)